# command not found: mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport, database, nosql

I use a `mongodb` database, I am on macOS, the command `mongoexport` does not pass, I am under the `/bin` directory of the database

here is my command

```
mongoexport --db Battleship --collection user --out resultExport.json
```

my database is Battleship , and the collection is user

any idea \?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `mongoexport` is in the same directory that your current one (and also is executable and you got perms to execute it) then you need to prepend executable with `./` and invoke it that way:

```
./mongoexport --db Battleship --collection user --out resultExport.json
```

Here's more on why you need that for https://askubuntu.com/a/320657/649099

Answer (score 2):

If there is a warning mongoexport command not found, you have to install

```
mongodb-org-tools
```

For centos users

```
yum install mongodb-org-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu:

Import the public key used by the package management system.

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Create a list file for MongoDB

Ubuntu 18.04:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

Ubuntu 20.04:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

Reload local package database.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the MongoDB packages.

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're on windows go to https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools download it make sure you pick msi then go to the path : `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin` open prompt and use `./mongoexport --db <source_db_name> --collection <source_collection_name> --out <exported_file_name>.json`